# use dse sqoop import data from RDBMS to Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax, sqoop

I followed this instruction: 
https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/ana/anaSqpDemo.html

1. Set HADOOP_ENABLED=1 from /etc/default/dse.
2. `sudo service dse start` or `dse cassandra -t`

Now I am able to use `dse hadoop`, which means Hadoop is enabled.

But When I try to run `dse sqoop import help` , I got this error :
Unable to start sqoop: jobtracker not found

Then I figured out I need to add credential, I added username and password, got this help information worked:

[image]

But when I tried to use dse sqoop import, I got this error:
[image]

I think it's because dse sqoop doesn't recognize cassandra arguments, but it's dse(datastax), how can it not recognize cassandra arguments? 
How to make it work? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You either start dse as a service or manually, not both. These two steps are redundant:

```
sudo service dse start
dse cassandra -t
```

Pick one.

If it's a package install, you should probably to the service so as to avoid breaking file permissions.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your suggestion is right. But problem still exist. I edit the problem, please have a look.